# Stream video from Windows Phone app to Windows Store app using Bluetooth or Wi-Fi direct?

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, windows-store-apps, video-streaming

I need to do reliable streaming of video from a Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Store app.  Currently I am doing this via sockets over Wi-Fi with a wireless router in the middle like this SO solution suggests:

[How to stream video from PC to Windows Phone 8 mobile phone through internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317270/how-to-stream-video-from-pc-to-windows-phone-8-mobile-phone-through-internet)

I can no longer use a solution like this because **the production environment for the apps will *not* have a wireless router available** so the Windows Phone device will need to talk directly to the Windows Store app running on a laptop or tablet.  I've heard of something called Wi-Fi direct but I am having trouble finding the information I need in this context.  Here are my questions:

> Can I use Wi-Fi direct?  If so, is there a decent sample or document that covers my app context of streaming video from a Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Store app?
>
> If I can't, is Bluetooth reliable enough to stream video smoothly?  If so, any examples that show how to do this would be appreciated.
>
> If both are viable solutions, which is the better one using smooth frame rate and reliability as a the criteria for judging?
>
> If I turn the tablet/PC or Windows Phone into a hotspot, would that allow me to establish socket connections from my apps?
>
> Hotspot questions extended.  Will the hotspot solution, either phone or tablet/laptop, still work if the device providing the hotspot does not currently have access to a network?  For example, if the phone can't access a 3G/4G network, can it still act as a hotspot for the tablet/laptop?  I know there won't be Internet/Web access, but can the devices still talk to each other?

I found this SO post on Wi-Fi direct but it covers Android:

[Wi-Fi Direct technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658272/wi-fi-direct-technology)

I found this SO post on Bluetooth streaming but it covers Android and iOS:

[Bluetooth video streaming in WiFiCameraApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172962/bluetooth-video-streaming-in-wificameraapp)

Would turning my laptop/tablet running the Windows Store app into a hot-spot work for my context?:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2207-accessing-files-over-wifi-without-a-router-android-pc

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the phone as a hot spot by enabling internet sharing? Remove the router.

Comment: Funny timing on this.  See the edit I just made on using the tablet/laptop as a hotspot instead of the phone.  I am most concerned about the network access question I added when it comes to using hotspots.